# Get all values of all rows in xml using Java

Tags: java

```
public class test{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String message="<ITEM><WBSTEST>test1</WBSTEST></ITEM><ITEM><WBSTEST>test2</WBSTEST></ITEM>";
        String item=message.substring(StringUtils.indexOf(message,"<ITEM>")+6,StringUtils.indexOf(message,"</ITEM>"));
        System.out.println("=====itemValue======"+item);
    }   
}
```

Output is:

```
=====itemValue======<WBSTEST>test1</WBSTEST>
```

What I want is like this:

```
=====itemValue======<WBSTEST>test1</WBSTEST>
=====itemValue======<WBSTEST>test2</WBSTEST>
```

Comment: What is the difference between what you get and what you want?

Comment: Don't post code as a comment, edit your post instead.

Comment: You know you can edit your question right?

Comment: what i want is like this:                                                 =====itemValue======<WBSTEST>test1</WBSTEST>                                    =====itemValue======<WBSTEST>test2</WBSTEST>

Comment: You need to do some reading about the programming concept of 'loops'.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
 public class ExploringThreads {
     public static void main(String args[]) {
            String input="<ITEM><WBSTEST>test1</WBSTEST></ITEM><ITEM><WBSTEST>test2</WBSTEST></ITEM>";
            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<WBSTEST>[^</WBSTEST>]*</WBSTEST>");
            Matcher m = pattern.matcher(input);
            while (m.find()) {
                String str = m.group();             
                System.out.println("=====itemValue======"+ str);

            }
        }
    }
```